# Ocaml fixed point implementation

Tags: ocaml, fixed-point-iteration

I'm trying to figure out how to implement fixed point iteration in Ocaml.  That is, given a function `f` and an `x`, I want to calculate what the final value of what `f(f(f(x)...))` will be.

So for example, if my function is `x/2` and my `x=50`, my answer should be 0.

So far, I have

```
 let rec computed_fixed_point eq f x =
        if (x == f x) then 
            x
        else
            computed_fixed_point eq f (f x)
```

This works for the function `x/2` and `x=50` (giving me 0), but for functions that go off to infinity or something other than 0, it doesn't seem to work.

Can another give me some advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's a little hard to understand the rationale of this problem. Not every function is going to have a fixed point. For example `fun x -> (x + 1) mod 5`. Not every function with a fixed point will reach the fixed point by repeated application from a distinct starting point. (I just did some googling, and fixed points like this are called "attractive fixed points".)

Here are some comments:

- You shouldn't use `==`, which is the physical equality operator. You possibly want to use `=`, equality of values.
- However, I don't see what the `eq` parameter is for. Perhaps the caller is allowed to specify what equality to use. If so, you should use this instead of `==`.

Comment: Nitpicking: I believe a fixpoint is "attractive" when some repeated application may *converge* towards it, but that does not guarantee that this convergence will reach its limit in fixed time (which is in fact the main problem here). The usual technique (say, in abstract interpretation) to guarantee convergence in finite time is to limit oneself to a domain of finite size.

Comment: Thanks, always happy to be corrected. (I only did a little googling to make sure my answer wasn't way off.)